# Are épier and espionner etymologically related?

Tags: étymologie

Both words have similar meanings, épier (to peek) and espionner (to spy). Also épier looks like espionner without the “s”, as many other Latin derived words that lose some “s” in French. Are these word related? I could not find their etymology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are definitely related but do not come from Latin.

The root is the old Frankish verb *spehôn (old German *[spehōną](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/speh%C5%8Dn%C4%85)*), to observe carefully which gave the French *espier* and later *épier*. The related substantives were *espie* and later *épie* (spy).

These substantives were superseded by *espion* under the influence of the Italian *[spione](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/%C3%A9pier/1)*.
This substantive finally gave a new verb *espionner*.

Needless to say, the English "spy" is part of the family.

Reference: [épier](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/%C3%A9pier/1) [espion](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/espion)